# Titanium appcelerator not list iPhone to load app in development mode

Tags: iphone, titanium, appcelerator, provisioning-profile, provisioning

Titanium appcelerator is not showing connected iPhone in development mode. I am using trail version of Titanium. Provisioning profile and certificates are OK (Green in run configuration).

When I try to press run button to install in iTunes. But, it gives --pp-uuid error.

Is it due to trial version? Please help me!

Comment: I don't think you can install to device with trial

Comment: Have you verified that the device's UUID is in the provisioning profile installed on the Mac?

Answer (score 2):

In the trial period, you can run App in device or simulator but can not package it for the iTunes or AdHoc build.

What version of Xcode and SDK do you have? Make it compatable with this link

http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Titanium_Compatibility_Matrix-section-src-29004837_TitaniumCompatibilityMatrix-Xcode

You can create new provisioning profile then download and install it. Also, follow this steps

- sudo npm install -g appcelerator
- appc use latest
- appc logout -D
- appc login
- appc setup

Hope this helps.